# How to write MySQL DB data to Excel File using Python?

Tags: python, excel

Below is my code, but this is not writing anything in file

```
import os
import pymysql
import pandas as pd
import csv

host = os.getenv('MYSQL_HOST')
port = os.getenv('MYSQL_PORT')
user = os.getenv('MYSQL_USER')
password = os.getenv('MYSQL_PASSWORD')
database = os.getenv('MYSQL_DATABASE')

conn = pymysql.connect(
    host=host,
    port=int(3306),
    user="root",
    passwd="Pass200",
    db="test_db",
    charset='utf8mb4')

QUERY='SELECT * FROM act;'

df = pd.read_sql_query("SELECT * FROM act",conn)
df.tail(10)
```

Above code successfully print SQL DB data. I appended below code to above code 
 for writing all data alongwith column names in EXCEL Sheet:

```
   cur=conn.cursor()
   cur.execute(QUERY)
   result=cur.fetchall()
   c = csv.writer(open('test.csv', 'w'))
   for x in result:
       print(x);
       c.writerow(x)
```

Kindly assist as I am new to this.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using pandas you can use `df.to_csv('test.csv')`